# Using .tupled method when companion object is in class

Tags: scala, singleton, slick, case-class

I am in the process of migrating from Slick to Slick 2, and in Slick 2 you are meant to use the `tupled` method when projecting onto a case class (as shown here http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0-RC1/migration.html)

The problem is when the case class has a companion object, i.e. if you have something like this

```
case class Person(firstName:String, lastName:String) {

}
```

Along with a companion object

```
object Person {
  def something = "rawr"
}
```

In the same scope, the `tupled` method no longer works, because its trying to run `tupled` on the `object`, instead of the `case class`.

Is there a way to retrieve the `case class` of `Person` rather than the `object`, so you can call `tupled` properly?

Comment: do you absolutely need the companion object? also, I think this is a general Scala question not really Slick related.

Comment: Yes I do, unless I want to refactor like half of my project (the companion object has a lot of helper methods for the case class in question)

And yes you are right, its not directly related to slick, just mentioned it because Slick may have its own workaround

Comment: You can't just rename the companion object and import the renamed object's contents directly to the case class? Alternatively, you can just make your custom companion object look like an autogenerated one manually.

Comment: Is what I am asking something impossible to do?

I mean I can do that (amongst various other options), but that object is used in hundreds of places, so it would be a pretty painful refactor

Comment: I've proposed a workaround, so no, it's not impossible, but it's ugly... overriding case class companion objects isn't really intended, otherwise what's the point of using the case class in the first place? case classes are afaik just syntactic sugar over regular classes + autogenerated companions with `apply` and `unapply`... if you override the autogen. companion, you're by definition defeating the purpose of case classes.

Comment: Well it was a design choice, you override the case class with an object for the same reason you use static final in java, that is, you want to attach helper methods onto a namespace

In this case I want to attach helper methods to the `Person` namespace, things like apply and unapply are just for creating an instance of Person (which case classes generate), however it doesn't have anything to do with the other methods that are attached to the `Person` type

Comment: As I said, you can put the helper functions in **any** object and import them to `Person`; it doesn't have to be a companion object.

Comment: Yes, but idiomatically speaking, if you have global functions that deal with `Person`, they should work on the `Person` namespace, thats the whole purpose of the Singleton Pattern

There is a reason when have global methods with `BigDecimal` (as an example), the methods are attached to `BigDecimal`, and not `BigDecimalHelpers` or something like that

Comment: It's hardly idiomatic to override and then re-implement the gist of case classes.

Comment: The intention to use an object with the same namespace as its `case class` is not to override the `case class`, the intention is to add methods/values from the `object` into the same namespace of the `case class`. This practice is done in almost every mainstream OOP language (including Java,Scala and others).

You are not overriding or reimplementing the `case classes` (unless you are defining `apply`, `unapply` in your `object`), you are adding ontop of the namespace.

Whether a `class` is a `case class` or a normal `class` is irrelevant, `case classes` just add an apply/unapply methods.

Comment: OK, I see, but when why did the `tupled` method disappear?

Comment: Actually they don't disappear, have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22368413/1519631. As to why the `tupled` method "disappears", I have no clue. After some quick reading, it may be down to how its brought into scopes by implicits (this is done internally).

Remember that you can still use `case classes` fine, even if there is a companion `object`. This issue only cropped up because I specifically needed to use the tupled method

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can also write

```
(Person.apply _).tupled
```

to avoid repeating the types.

Comment: What if the companion object has its own apply method (an overloaded constructor)? Compiler cannot resolve the apply...

Comment: Found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179532/when-overloading-apply-method-slick-error-message-value-tupled-is-not-a-memb

Comment: this is not compiling: `apply` not found

Comment: @javadba Yes, it is: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/a5rsgke/0. Are you sure you have a case class?

Answer (score 25):

This is very similar to what Alexey Romanov said, but in order to avoid lifting `apply` whenever you need `tupled`, we just add it to our companion objects.

```
object Person {
  def something = "rawr"
  def tupled = (Person.apply _).tupled
}
```

Now you can call `Person.tupled` just like you would have if it didn't have a companion object.

Answer (score 7):

One workaround is define a companion object as follows:

```
object Person extends((String,String) => Person) {
    ...
}
```

See. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-user/jyWBMz5Qslw/Bryv4ftzRLgJ

Comment: Thanks, that actually works (I assume there isn't any workaround for the boilerplate that is (String,String) )

Answer (score 4):

To build on some of the other comments you could do the following as well since tuple is calling the generated default apply method for the case class.

```
object Person {
  ...
  def tupled = (this.apply _).tupled
}
```