# In scala, how to avoid class method hiding by companion object

Tags: scala, slick

When defining Slick table projections like this:

```
def * = (id.?, email, human, langUser, langLearn) <> (User2.tupled, User2.unapply)
```

I observe that `tupled` method becomes invisible as soon as I define `object User2`.

My question is what is going on and how to avoid method hiding by companion objects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using .tupled method when companion object is in class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367092/using-tupled-method-when-companion-object-is-in-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duplicate of: [Using .tupled method when companion object is in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367092/using-tupled-method-when-companion-object-is-in-class)

Tupled on custom case class companions requires manually extending a function type See: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3664  https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4808