# If scala case class and object have same name, how to import case class only

Tags: scala

Well I have a scala class `Foo.scala` containing these two elements,

First One,

```
case class Foo(
.
.
.
)
```

And secondly,

```
object Foo{
.
.
.
}
```

Now when I import the Foo in some other file, I want to use the case class not the Object, but when I import the file, object instance is returned in Foo<= this is the object,(I needed to do Foo.apply, Foo.tupled)

Is there anyway I can get the Foo to act as the case class then an object.

Comment: Is their any possibility that you can change name of any one either of **case class** or **object**?

Comment: No can't do, can't change the object/case class name since I am working with legacy code, so don't know where else my change would affect the codebase.

Comment: is this similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367092/using-tupled-method-when-companion-object-is-in-class ?

Comment: Yup, t'was similar, thanks for the link @shyamendra-solanki, it helped a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
 (Foo.apply _).tupled
```

Answer (score 0):

You have ambiguity in your scala namespaces. A simple solution to the problem would be to nest the case class inside of the object, then import it with

`import Foo.Foo`

another solution would be to place them in separate packages. Depending on your system design this could affect the cohesiveness of your packages, which in my mind is probably more important.

Comment: Yes, case class and object name should not have been the same , and its a legacy code not my work, so I cant change their positions, like you have suggested.

Comment: If you can't change their position that must mean some one else is dependent upon the import, which implies that some one had already figured out how to import the case class instead of the object?

Comment: seems like there is an solution to my problem, solutions in this link ===> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367092/using-tupled-method-when-companion-object-is-in-class as pointed out shyamendra