# When overloading `apply` method: Slick error message 'value tupled is not a member of object'

Tags: scala, slick

I need an ability to create a `User` object by providing all the values except `id` in certain cases, such that the `User` object takes care of assigning itself an auto-generated value.

For this I have overloaded the apply method in the companion object, like shown below. But this is causing the compile time error: `value tupled is not a member of object`.

Solutions mentioned on StackOverflow and other blogs aren't working, such as:
http://queirozf.com/entries/slick-error-message-value-tupled-is-not-a-member-of-object

```
case class User(id: Long, firstName: String, lastName: String, mobile: Long, email: String)

object User {
  private val seq = new AtomicLong

  def apply(firstName: String, lastName: String, mobile: Long, email: String): User = {
    User(seq.incrementAndGet(), firstName, lastName, mobile, email)
  }
}

class UserTableDef(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "user") {

  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def firstName = column[String]("first_name")
  def lastName = column[String]("last_name")
  def mobile = column[Long]("mobile")
  def email = column[String]("email")

  override def * =
    (id, firstName, lastName, mobile, email) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)

}
```

Comment: Avoid using something like application code generated long as id's. You can  either leave it to the database to manage this by having `id` as `Option[Long]` or you can use something like UUID.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The source of your problem is that overloaded `apply` def.

`tupled` does not work with `case class`'s with `less than 2 parameters` or `overloaded apply`.

As far as slick's `*` (or all) mapping and `<>` is concerned, it is supposed to be like,

```
def * = (tupleMember1, tupleMember2, ...) <> (func1, func2)
```

Such that,

- `func1` takes that tuple `(tupleMember1, tupleMember2, ...)` as input and returns an instance of mapped class/case class.
- `func1` takes an instance of mapped class/case class and returns that tuple `(tupleMember1, tupleMember2, ...)`.

So you can provide any function... which meets these requirements.

```
case class User(id: Long, firstName: String, lastName: String, mobile: Long, email: String)

object User {
  private val seq = new AtomicLong

  def apply(firstName: String, lastName: String, mobile: Long, email: String): User = {
    User(seq.incrementAndGet(), firstName, lastName, mobile, email)
  }

  def mapperTo(
    id: Long, firstName: String,
    lastName: String, mobile: Long, email: String
  ) = apply(id, firstName, lastName, mobile, email)

}

class UserTableDef(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "user") {

  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def firstName = column[String]("first_name")
  def lastName = column[String]("last_name")
  def mobile = column[Long]("mobile")
  def email = column[String]("email")

  override def * =
    (id, firstName, lastName, mobile, email) <> ((User.mapperTo _).tupled, User.unapply)

}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works fine. But I stumbled upon a follow up issue when declaring implicit serializer `implicit val userReads = Json.reads[User]`: **ambiguous reference to overloaded definition, both method apply in object User of type (id: Option[Long], firstName: String, lastName: String, mobile: Long, email: String)models.User and method apply in object User of type (firstName: String, lastName: String, mobile: Long, email: String)models.User match expected type ?**

Comment: yes... that will happen with the reader macro of Play Json. You can write your own reads implementation.

Comment: Following solution worked for serializer issue: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2148 https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonCombinators

Comment: Correct signature of `mapperTo` method would be: `def mapperTo(id: Long, firstName: String, lastName: String, mobile: Long, email: String) = apply(id, firstName, lastName, mobile, email)`

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to push the `secondary constructor` to the `case class` definition itself and then use the work around mentioned in the blog post specified in the question.

You can then create `User` objects without specifying `id`, however, you may need still to use `new` keyword, like so `new User(firstName, lastName, mobile, email)`.

```
case class User(id: Long, firstName: String, lastName: String, mobile: Long, email: String) {

  def this(firstName: String, lastName: String, mobile: Long, email: String) =
    this(User.seq.incrementAndGet(), firstName, lastName, mobile, email)
}

object User {
  private val seq = new AtomicLong
}

class UserTableDef(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "user") {

  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def firstName = column[String]("first_name")
  def lastName = column[String]("last_name")
  def mobile = column[Long]("mobile")
  def email = column[String]("email")

  override def * =
    (id, firstName, lastName, mobile, email) <> ((User.apply _).tupled, User.unapply)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Notice: It is probably a bad idea to use an internal atomic long as an
>   id generator instead of using auto-increment sequence generator that
>   database provide, as these are safe against concurrent access from
>   multiple applications.

Now getting back to the code, the **tupled** method is defined on a Function and converts a function with **N arguments** into a function with a **single** argument, **a tuple of N-arity**

From your description, it looks like overloading the apply method results in the compiler not being able to determine which "apply" implementation should be picked. So there are two things you should probably do:

1. Rename the second apply (and in general, please avoid overloading)
2. Explicitly call tupled (i.e. User.withEmptyId.tupled)

Comment: The compiler does not automatically generate `apply` methods for secondary constructors in case classes. We can however overload `Person.apply` in the companion object, we can have our convenient
“constructors” and avoid the requirement to use `new`. Programming in Scala By Dean Wampler. Could you please elaborate on your statement "and in general, please avoid overloading" in this context? Renaming the apply method won't serve the purpose here, right?

Comment: "auto-increment sequence generator that database provide" ::: Could you also please explain how to achieve this in Slick? May be you could point me to some link? Much thanks!

Comment: In general overloading could case problem with type inference , because every method is a function. Look at the following statement: val a = User.apply. How can the compiler know which apply are we talking about?

Comment: I just changed `id: Long` to `id: Option[Long]` and created `User` like so `this(None, firstName, lastName, mobile, email)` by passing `None` as `id` and Slick took care of providing an auto-incremented value for the `id`. Thanks a lot!