# Insert record into Db using Slick (Scala), Best practices for an Entity

Tags: mysql, database, scala, slick

First to say, I'm newcomer in Scala and really need a little help. I need to build a web api, and I'll try to insert one record into database, but have some problems with mapping the entity (db table) into a model (class). I worked with .Net Core Web API (there I used Entity Framework Core, here in Scala use Slick) and try to keep same arhitecture in Scala, but need some more informations, because on the internet I find a lot of versions, and can not choose the best.
As database, MySQL is used.

**User.scala**

```
        case class User(
                     id: Int = 0,
                     userName: String,
                     firstName: String,
                     lastName: String
                   ) {
      override def equals(that: Any): Boolean = true
    }

    object User {    
      implicit object UserFormat extends Format[User] {
        def writes(user: User): JsValue = {
          val userSeq = Seq(
            "id" -> JsNumber(user.id),
            "userName" -> JsString(user.userName),
            "firstName" -> JsString(user.firstName),
            "lastName" -> JsString(user.lastName)
          )
          JsObject(userSeq)
        }

        def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[User] = {    
          JsSuccess(User(
            (json \ "id").as[Int].value,
            (json \ "userName").as[String].value,
            (json \ "firstName").as[String].value,
            (json \ "lastName").as[String].value)
          )
        }
      }

      def tupled = (this.apply _).tupled
    }

class UserMap @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)(implicit ex: ExecutionContext) {
  val dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] = dbConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]
  val db: JdbcBackend#DatabaseDef = dbConfig.db
  val dbUsers = TableQuery[UserDef]

  def getAll(): Unit = {
    val action = sql"SELECT Id, UserName, FirstName, LastName FROM Users".as[(Int, String, String, String)]
    return db.run(action)
  }

  def add(user: User): Future[Seq[User]] = {
    dbUsers += user
    db.run(dbUsers.result)
  }
}
```

**UserDef.scala** (which is a mapper of db table / entity)

```
  class UserDef(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "Users") {
  def id = column[Int]("Id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def userName = column[String]("UserName")
  def firstName = column[String]("FirstName")
  def lastName = column[String]("LastName")

  override def * = (id, userName, firstName, lastName) <> (create, extract)

  def create(user: (Int, String, String, String)): User = User(user._1, user._2, user._3, user._4)
  def extract(user: User): Option[(Int, String, String, String)] = Some((user.id, user.userName,user.firstName,user.lastName))
}
```

**UsersController.scala**

```
    def createUser = Action(parse.json) { implicit request => {
    val userJson = request.body

    var user = new User(
      -1,
      (userJson \ "userName").as[String].value,
      (userJson \ "firstName").as[String].value,
      (userJson \ "lastName").as[String].value
    )

    var users = TableQuery[UserDef]
    Await.result(db.run(DBIO.seq(
      users += user,
      users.result.map(println))), Duration.Inf
    )

    Ok(Json.toJson(user))
  }
  }
```

How I see the problem:

- UserDef is an Entity and must remain clean, only table columns definitions
- UserMap is the bridge between User class and UserDef (entity), can be used as a repository with crud methods (getAll(), getById(id), create(user), update(user), delete(id)). This is in same file as User class, but probably must be moved in another.
- User class is the model and need to contain only their parameters and writes/reads (Scala specifics)

and now in the controller:

If I try to insert a record into database, with current method, first I need to get all rows from table, and then to add the new record in the list. What happening if I have 3 4mil records in this table? Will get all these rows useless to insert only a new row.

Then, after inserting this new row, I need to return it into client, but how I can get it updated (Id is every time -1, but if I get entire list to see what it contain, I can see the correct id for the newest entity)

thx

Comment: Why do you need to get all rows from the table to insert a new record?  `users += user` only does the insert, it does not get any rows.

Comment: For getting the inserted row id, you can use the `returning` clause on insert, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31448129/14955

Comment: `UserMap` is a good thing to have. Why do you have `db.run` code in your controller instead of calling the `add` method in `UserMap`?  Why does `add` return a `Seq[User]` instead of just the newly added single `User` or its new id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a good solution and post it here, maybe somebody need this:

**UserMap**, for me at least will become UserRepository. There I have CRUD operations and maybe some extra :

```
  def getAll(): Future[Seq[User]] = {
    db.run(dbUsers.result)
  }

  def getById(id: Int): Future[Option[User]] ={
    val action = dbUsers.filter(_.id === id).result.headOption
    db.run(action)
  }

  def create(user: User): Future[User] = {
    val insertQuery = dbUsers returning dbUsers.map(_.id) into ((x, id) => x.copy(id = id))
    val action = insertQuery += user
    db.run(action)
  }

  def update(user: User) {
    Try( dbUsers.filter(_.id === user.id).update(user)) match {
      case Success(response) => db.run(response)
      case Failure(_) => println("An error occurred!")
    }
  }

  def delete(id: Int) {
    Try( dbUsers.filter(_.id === id).delete) match {
      case Success(response) => db.run(response)
      case Failure(_) => println("An error occurred!")
    }
  }
```

and UsersController:

```
  def getAll() = Action {
    var users = Await.result(usersRepository.getAll(), Duration.Inf)
    Ok(Json.toJson(users))
  }

  def getById(id: Int) = Action { implicit request => {
    val user = Await.result(usersRepository.getById(id), Duration.Inf)

    Ok(Json.toJson(user))
    }
  }

  def create = Action(parse.json) { implicit request => {
    val userJson = request.body

    var user = new User(
      -1,
      (userJson \ "userName").as[String].value,
      (userJson \ "firstName").as[String].value,
      (userJson \ "lastName").as[String].value
    )
    var createdUser = Await.result(usersRepository.create((user)), Duration.Inf)
    Ok(Json.toJson(createdUser))
    }
  }

  def update(id: Int) = Action(parse.json) { implicit request => {
    val userJson = request.body

    var user = new User(
      (userJson \ "id").as[Int].value,
      (userJson \ "userName").as[String].value,
      (userJson \ "firstName").as[String].value,
      (userJson \ "lastName").as[String].value
    )

    var updatedUser = usersRepository.update(user)
    Ok(Json.toJson(user))
    }
  }

  def delete(id: Int) = Action {
    usersRepository.delete(id)
    Ok("true")
  }
```

Anyway, I know I have some bad blocks of code there...especially in create & update methods, where convert json to User.

Comment: Yes, good start!  Once you are comfortable with Scala and Slick, do take a look at how to use `Action.async` to get rid of the `Await.result` code.

Comment: thanks. Yes, I need to implement async await in two more methods (update/delete) and to thread the errors

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to give it a try, and here is a full working example of a Play 2.7/Scala 2.13/Slick 4.0.2 REST-API controller bound to a MySQL database.

Since you are starting with Scala, maybe it is a bit overwhelming at first to get eased with Play, Slick, etc...

So here is an humble skeleton (derived from [Play-Slick GitHub](https://github.com/playframework/play-slick))

So first, since we want to write an API, here is the `conf/routes` file:

```
GET           /users              controllers.UserController.list()
GET           /users/:uuid        controllers.UserController.get(uuid: String)
POST          /users              controllers.UserController.create()
PUT           /users              controllers.UserController.update()
DELETE        /users/:uuid        controllers.UserController.delete(uuid: String)
```

Nothing to fancy here, we just bind routes to functions in the upcoming controller.
Just notice that the 2nd GET and the DELETE expect an `UUID` as query param, while Json bodies with be used for the POST and PUT.

It would be nice to see the model right now, in `app/models/User.scala`:

```
package models

import java.util.UUID

import play.api.libs.json.{Json, OFormat}

case class User(
                 uuid: UUID,
                 username: String,
                 firstName: String,
                 lastName: String
               ) {
}

object User {

  // this is because defining a companion object shadows the case class function tupled
  // see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367092/using-tupled-method-when-companion-object-is-in-class
  def tupled = (User.apply _).tupled

  // provides implicit json mapping
  implicit val format: OFormat[User] = Json.format[User]
}
```

I used an `uuid` instead using a numerical id, but basically, it is the same.
Notice that a Json serializer/deserializer can be written in just one line (you don't need to detail it with case classes). I think it is also a good practice to not override it to produce `Seq` as found on your code, since this serializer will be very usefull when converting objects to Json on the controller.

Now the `tupled` definition is most likelly a hack (see comment) that will be required later on the `DAO`...

Next, we need a controller in `app/controllers/UserController.scala`:

```
package controllers

import java.util.UUID

import forms.UserForm
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.Logger
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.i18n.I18nSupport
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.mvc._
import services.UserService

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

class UserController @Inject()(userService: UserService)
                              (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends InjectedController with I18nSupport {

  lazy val logger: Logger = Logger(getClass)

  def create: Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { implicit request =>
    withFormErrorHandling(UserForm.create, "create failed") { user =>
      userService
        .create(user)
        .map(user => Created(Json.toJson(user)))
    }
  }

  def update: Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { implicit request =>
    withFormErrorHandling(UserForm.create, "update failed") { user =>
      userService
        .update(user)
        .map(user => Ok(Json.toJson(user)))
    }
  }

  def list: Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { implicit request =>
    userService
      .getAll()
      .map(users => Ok(Json.toJson(users)))
  }

  def get(uuid: String): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { implicit request =>
    Try(UUID.fromString(uuid)) match {
      case Success(uuid) =>
        userService
          .get(uuid)
          .map(maybeUser => Ok(Json.toJson(maybeUser)))
      case Failure(_) => Future.successful(BadRequest(""))
    }
  }

  def delete(uuid: String): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async {
    Try(UUID.fromString(uuid)) match {
      case Success(uuid) =>
        userService
          .delete(uuid)
          .map(_ => Ok(""))
      case Failure(_) => Future.successful(BadRequest(""))
    }
  }

  private def withFormErrorHandling[A](form: Form[A], onFailureMessage: String)
                                      (block: A => Future[Result])
                                      (implicit request: Request[AnyContent]): Future[Result] = {
    form.bindFromRequest.fold(
      errors => {
        Future.successful(BadRequest(errors.errorsAsJson))
      }, {
        model =>
          Try(block(model)) match {
            case Failure(e) => {
              logger.error(onFailureMessage, e)
              Future.successful(InternalServerError)
            }

            case Success(eventualResult) => eventualResult.recover {
              case e =>
                logger.error(onFailureMessage, e)
                InternalServerError
            }
          }
      })
  }
}
```

So here:

1. basically, each of our 5 functions referenced from the `routes` file check input, and then delegate the work to an injected `UserService` (more on that later)
2. for the `create` and `update` functions, you can see that we use [Play Forms](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaForms) that I think is also a good practice. Their role is to validate the incoming Json, and that Marshall it into a `User` type.
3. Also, you can see that we use `Action.async`: Scala offers a very powerfull leverage with `Futures` so lets use it! Basically by doing so, you ensure that your code is not-blocking, thus easing the IOPS on your hardware.
4. Finally for the case of GET (one), GET (all), POST and PUT, since we return users, and have a deseralizer, a simple `Json.toJson(user)` do the work.

Before jumping to service and dao, lets see the form, in `app/forms/UserForm.scala`:

```
package forms

import java.util.UUID

import models.User
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms.{mapping, nonEmptyText, _}

object UserForm {
  def create: Form[User] = Form(
    mapping(
      "uuid" -> default(uuid, UUID.randomUUID()),
      "username" -> nonEmptyText,
      "firstName" -> nonEmptyText,
      "lastName" -> nonEmptyText,
    )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
  )
}
```

Nothing too fancy here, just as the doc says, although there is just a trick : when no uuid is defined (in the POST case, then we generate one).

Now, the service... not so much required in this very case, but in practice it might be a good thing to have an extra layer (dealing with acls for example), in `app/services/UserService.scala`:

```
package services

import java.util.UUID

import dao.UserDAO
import javax.inject.Inject
import models.User

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

class UserService @Inject()(dao: UserDAO)(implicit ex: ExecutionContext) {

  def get(uuid: UUID): Future[Option[User]] = {
    dao.get(uuid)
  }

  def getAll(): Future[Seq[User]] = {
    dao.all()
  }
  def create(user: User): Future[User] = {
    dao.insert(user)
  }

  def update(user: User): Future[User] = {
    dao.update(user)
  }

  def delete(uuid: UUID): Future[Unit] = {
    dao.delete(uuid)
  }
}
```

As you can see, here, it is just a wrapper around the dao, and finnally the dao in `app/dao/UserDao.scala`:

```
package dao

import java.util.UUID

import javax.inject.Inject
import models.User
import play.api.db.slick.{DatabaseConfigProvider, HasDatabaseConfigProvider}
import play.db.NamedDatabase
import slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

class UserDAO @Inject()(@NamedDatabase("mydb") protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {

  import profile.api._

  private val users = TableQuery[UserTable]

  def all(): Future[Seq[User]] = db.run(users.result)

  def get(uuid: UUID): Future[Option[User]] = {
    db.run(users.filter(_.uuid === uuid).result.headOption)
  }

  def insert(user: User): Future[User] = {
    db.run(users += user).map(_ => user)
  }

  def update(user: User): Future[User] = {
    db.run(users.filter(_.uuid === user.uuid).update(user)).map(_ => user)
  }

  def delete(uuid: UUID): Future[Unit] = {
    db.run(users.filter(_.uuid === uuid).delete).map(_ => ())
  }

  private class UserTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") {

    def uuid = column[UUID]("uuid", O.PrimaryKey)
    def username = column[String]("username")
    def firstName = column[String]("firstName")
    def lastName = column[String]("lastName")

    def * = (uuid, username, firstName, lastName) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
  }
}
```

So, here I have just adapted the code from the official play-slick example, so I guess, I do not have better comment than theirs...

Hope, the whole things helps to get a better picture :)
If something is unclear, feel free to ask!